# rails manual column for date time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created another column with

```
t.datetime :update_at  #Created because this is one time update
```

And in my update I used `update_at: DateTime.now` which created `2013-12-21 06:30:33` in my table but when I try to find the difference of date with

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(post.created_at, post.update_at) %>
```

getting error as `undefined method`to_datetime' for nil:NilClass`

```
eg: created_at is 2013-12-20 07:02:28.386126 and update_at is 2013-12-21 06:30:33
```

Comment: do `post.created_at` return the right value? Could you include the post model with relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

`post.created_at` or `post.update_at` is returning nil. My guess is the latter. This may happen if the `post` variable wasn't reloaded after updating (still contains the old version).

Reload/restart the server and try again.